# Validate multiple textboxes with two values to summarize report

Tags: vba, if-statement, ms-word

For our machines we have multiple validation phases. Each phase needs to be "OK" or  "N/A" before we can send the machine of to the customer. I have multiple textboxes where they fill in whether the specific phase is "OK" or "NOK"(not oke) or "N/A".

If everything is "OK" or "N/A" then `MouldTotal.value="OK" Else MouldTotal.value="NOK"`

I cant get this to work and have not found a way that is applicable for this situation.

Thanks for any help in advance.

For the first code below I recieved an error 13 type match.

```
If DryCycle_status.Value = "OK" Or "N/A" And Temp_status = "OK" Or "N/A" And _ 
BackPressure_status.Value = "OK" Or "N/A" And _
Filling_status = "OK" Or "N/A" And Injection_status.Value = "OK" Or "N/A" _ 
And HoldingPressure_status = "OK" Or "N/A" _
And CoolingTime_status.Value = "OK" Or "N/A" And ClampingForce_status = "OK" Or "N/A" And _
ProcessStability_status.Value = "OK" Or "N/A" And AdditionalTesting_status = "OK" Or "N/A" _
Then MouldTotal.Value = "OK" Else MouldTotal.Value = "NOK"
```

I have also tried the code below. This one didnt result in an error but also didnt do anything with the code. It appears to just read the value of `MouldTotal`.

Edit; it only seems to read `DryCycle_status`, because when I change this one to "NOK", then `MouldTotal` does change to "NOK". When I change any other "status" it doesnt affect `MouldTotal`

```
If DryCycle_status.Value = "OK" Or DryCycle_status.Value = "N/A" And _
Temp_status = "OK" Or Temp_status.Value = "N/A" And _
BackPressure_status.Value = "OK" Or BackPressure_status.Value = "N/A" And _
Filling_status = "OK" Or Filling_status.Value = "N/A" And _
Injection_status.Value = "OK" Or Injection_status.Value = "N/A" And _
HoldingPressure_status = "OK" Or _
HoldingPressure_status.Value = "N/A" And CoolingTime_status.Value = "OK" Or _
CoolingTime_status.Value = "N/A" And ClampingForce_status = "OK" Or _
ClampingForce_status.Value = "N/A" And _
ProcessStability_status.Value = "OK" Or ProcessStability_status.Value =  "N/A" _
And AdditionalTesting_status = "OK" Or AdditionalTesting_status.Value  = "N/A" _
Then MouldTotal.Value = "OK" Else MouldTotal.Value = "NOK"
```

Comment: Unfortunately you provide no details about *HOW* it "doesn't work". That makes trouble-shooting very difficult. But FWIW at a glance... This formulation `If DryCycle_status.Value = "OK" Or "N/A"` is not allowed in VBA. It needs to be `If DryCycle_status.Value = "OK" Or DryCycle_status.Value = "N/A"` - it's necessary to state *both sides* of the comparison with each comparison operator - no shortcuts.

Comment: @CindyMeister; sorry I didnt elaborate on why it didnt work. I recieved a `Error 13 type match`. I have also tried the way you suggest (I will edit into the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a work around. It aint pretty, but works for me. I want the summary to say **"NOK"** whenever there is 1 or more **"NOK"** or empty fields **""**. This is what the code below does for me.

```
If DryCycle_status.Value = "NOK" Or Temp_status = "NOK" Or BackPressure_status.Value = "NOK" Or _
Filling_status = "NOK" Or Injection_status.Value = "NOK" Or HoldingPressure_status "NOK" _
Or CoolingTime_status.Value = "NOK" Or ClampingForce_status = "NOK" Or _
ProcessStability_status.Value = "NOK" Or AdditionalTesting_status = "NOK" _
DryCycle_status.Value = "" Or Temp_status = "" Or BackPressure_status.Value = "" Or _
Filling_status = "" Or Injection_status.Value = "" Or HoldingPressure_status = "" _
Or CoolingTime_status.Value = "" Or ClampingForce_status = "" Or _
ProcessStability_status.Value = "" Or AdditionalTesting_status = "" Then 
MouldTotal.Value = "NOK" Else MouldTotal.Value = "OK"
```